# Finding JS max integer value in a funny way fails

Tags: javascript

Today I tried to find a funny and mysterious way to determine JavaScript's maximal integer value. One of the approaches was the following:

```
~(+!!![]) >>> (+!![]);
```

which evaluates actually to

```
~0 >>> 1
```

but it returns 2147483647 and not 4294967295 as it should. Why? Of course, the latter one would be the result of this operation for an unsigned integer, while my result is correct for a signed one. But how to force it?..

Comment: One question 4294967295 is not the max intger value in Javascript. Or you were just checking max 32 bit int value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're finding the maximum integer, and then shifting it to the right 1 bit, which divides it by 2. Use:

```
~0 >>> 0
```

to get the maximum integer.

Converting that to the "funny" way I'll leave as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: What does ">>> 0" ? Shifting by 0 bits isn't the same thing again?

Comment: It is. But you have to use the `>>>` operator to get an unsigned result.

Comment: My approach does: 1111..1111 and than shift: 011111...111. What you do is 111111111111111 and shift nothing but delete sign bit: 0111...1111. What is the difference ? ? ?

Comment: I'm not deleting the sign bit. I'm treating `1111...1111` as unsigned.

Comment: Ok, this explains it. Thank you. +1 from me. Cheers